# getting Objects are not valid as a React child error in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, next.js

I was trying to make a blog with Next.js and I had to create a custom react hook. When i tried to run my code I got the following error.

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

on the following code on   `setUsername(doc.data()?.username);`

```
import { auth, firestore } from './firebase';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

// Custom hook to read  auth record and user profile doc
export function useUserData() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // turn off realtime subscription
    let unsubscribe;

    if (user) {
      const ref = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
      unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot((doc) => {
        setUsername(doc.data()?.username);
      });
    } else {
      setUsername(null);
    }

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user]);

  return { user, username };
}
```

Here is the code where this hooks is used

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { UserContext } from "../lib/Context";
import { useUserData } from "../lib/hooks";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const userData = useUserData();

  return (
    <>
      <UserContext.Provider value={userData}>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
          />
          <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
          ></script>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css"
            integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
          />
        </Head>
        <Navbar />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}


export default MyApp;
```

here is the code where i am using `userData`

```
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../lib/Context";
import { auth, googleAuthProvider, firestore} from "../lib/firebase";

export default function Enter({}) {
  const { user, username } = useContext(UserContext);
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container my-3">
        {user ? !username ? <UserNameForm /> : router.push("/") : <Login />}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

//button for login
const Login = () => {
  const signinwithgoogle = async () => {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      return <h3>some error occured</h3>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h3>Signup or Login with google</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center my-4">
        <button onClick={signinwithgoogle} className="btn btn-primary">
          Sign up <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

//Username form
const UserNameForm = () => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState("");
  const {user,username} = useContext(UserContext)
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create refs for both documents
    const userDoc = firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const usernameDoc = firestore.doc(`usernames/${formValue}`);

    // Commit both docs together as a batch write.
    const batch = firestore.batch();
    batch.set(userDoc, { username: formValue, photoURL: user.photoURL, displayName: user.displayName });
    batch.set(usernameDoc, { uid: user.uid });

    await batch.commit();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">
            Email address
          </label>
          <input
            value={formValue}
            onChange={onChange}
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="exampleInputEmail1"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            minLength={4}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

here is the image of the error
[image: error]

when I run the local host server it gives the error. I even tried to recode the hook but it didn't work. Hope someone can help.

Comment: No all the react components are not async but functions in them are, i checked all of my files. I have edited the, i stated at which line i got the error. Maybe that will help

Comment: Can you explain what is this line `user ? !username ? <UserNameForm /> : router.push("/") : <Login />` trying to achieve? You can't just have `router.push("/")` in there. `router.push` returns a promise, so that might be where the error comes from.

Comment: so what should i do instead?

Comment: Move the `router.push("/")` inside a `useEffect` instead.

Comment: yes that worked, i removed the ```router.push('/')``` and it started working fine.
 Thanks alot